# plot multiple rows using seaborn or matplotlib in python

Tags: python, pandas, graph

Below is what my data looks like:

[raw dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDxQ7.png)
The product_group_code is unique and contains no duplicates, with 108 of them. This dataframe shows how a product group's value changes before and after Trump was elected.

My goal is to plot 108 lines for the product_group_code's values with only two timestamps: before_Trump and after_Trump.

I hereby kindly request your assistance, as I have not found any solution online. **My biggest problem is to transform the above dataframe into the data where seaborn and matplotlib can easily apply, as the time variable is embedded in the before_Trump_value and after_Trump_value.**

**Hence, the line graph's x = 2 time stamps (i.e., 'before Trump' and 'after Trump'). y = value (i.e., 'before Trump_value' and 'after Trump_value'). Legend is the 'product_group_code' so that people know the meaning of each line.**

Thank you. Hope the above clarifies many doubts about my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df['column_name'].tolist()` for data retrieval.

```
legend_handles = df['product_group_code'].tolist()
x1 = df['before_Trump'].tolist()
x2 = df['after_Trump'].tolist()
y1 = df['before_Trump_value'].tolist()
y2 = df['after_Trump_value'].tolist()
```

which effectively extracts required data, although it's not yet suitable for plotting. Let's combine it in the right way

```
x_full = np.transpose([x1,x2])
y_full = np.transpose([y1,y2])
```

Now those two lists should contain 108 elements, each element representing data for a single line's x or y. Let's further manipulate those

```
data_collection = np.transpose([x_full,y_full])
```

`data_collection` is in a from of `[(x,y), (x1,y1),...]`

You may try `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection` from `matplotlib` package for efficient plotting of these multiple lines. Official documentation also provides an [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/collections.html) with different additional features that can be excluded.

A loose example

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(9, 6))
segments = LineCollection(
    data_collection
)
ax1.add_collection(segments)
ax1.legend(handles=legend_handles)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I see your point. I know how to use plt and seaborn. It is just that I am not sure how to transpose this data to make it easily suit the format required for plotting. Thanks

Comment: Reading '108 lines' I suppose that there are 108 array pairs: 108 x arrays and 108 y arrays. Where are those located in dataframe? Sorry, but I can't figure it out by myself from the question.

Comment: Sorry. I realized that u probably cannot see the photo. Now can u see it? I attached my raw dataframe as a link named "an example of my current dataframe". Thx

Comment: No, the photo was perfectly visible, I just don't get what exactly needs to be plotted. If we are plotting y(x), what are the y, and what are the x. I get that there are 108 rows in the dataframe, what I don't get is what 'lines' are

Comment: Please see the updated post. I make it very clear now. Thank you!

Comment: I edited the answer adding step-by-step retrieval. Hope it works